# Is there a way to generate OpenClient .NET proxies through the command line?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, appserver

I want a painless way to be able to generate progress OpenClient proxies for .NET.

I find there isn't anything pleasant about the proxy generation process, in fact I almost always punch a screen when I have to use it.

My current problem is it's putting stupid ending comments in the source files which are invalid stating `* END COMMENTING OUT DATASET CLASS */`. It deletes the files though and just gives the CSC error which you then needs to quickly trap the files before being deleted.

So, does anyone know of a painless way to reliably generate proxies from the command line that does not have hard-coded values for CSC and XSD paths etc.

Better yet, if anyone knows when progress will get off their butt and finally develop a proper SQL driver for .NET I'd love to hear about it, I never want to see the app-server ever again.

Answer (score 3):

Unsure what versions this is supported in, and I haven't tried it myself but there is some kind of support for a "batch mode" when creating open client proxies.

Quoting from the "Open Client Introduction and Programming" manual (This is from 11.2, I found the feature in version 10.1 as well so it's probably been there a good while).

**Running Batch ProxyGen**

Batch ProxyGen runs on supported UNIX and Windows platforms. It allows you to
generate Open Client proxies and/or a Web service definition based on the Open Client
interface you defined in a project file created using ProxyGen.
To run Batch ProxyGen, enter the following command in the Windows or UNIX
command prompt:

Syntax

```
bproxygen -xpxgfile project-filename.xpxg [ -useWildCard ] [ -leaveproxyfiles ]
```

Here is a link to the latest version (11.3) of the documentation:
[Progress PSDN](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1107.openedge-11-3-product-documentation.aspx)